# how to implement using an iframe paypal button

Tags: paypal

I am trying to implement the PayPal checkout button using an iframe. The problem is when I click the paypal button in the parent html a PayPal popup comes out. It is possible to make that black window disappear or cover the size of the parent html, so that it does not appear only in the iframe.

Screenshots:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ipNvgvK7ATceFJWVhEtkP7ZVmw-YevVI?usp=sharing

PayPal Documentation:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/checkout/integrate/#1-get-the-code

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're using the old deprecated checkout.js

Try the current sdk.js https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

Comment: I've tried. It doesn't work. the black paypal popup takes the size of the iframe

Comment: It's normal for the buttons to take up the full width of the container. From the screenshots it's hard to tell what your actual complaint is.

Comment: I want that when I click on the paypal button, the modal of black color of paypal opens in the parent html and not the full width of the container. I've upload a extra image.

Comment: Well it seems you're asking for something that by design is not possible. A separate window opens so that the input is seen to be `https://www.paypal.com` and hence is secure, embedded HTML on your website would not be secure.  Your opening site is tinted with a lightbox, and the message in the center should be covered (you moved the PayPal modal out of the way it seems)